# R - Creating New Column Based off of a Partial String

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a large dataset (Dataset "A") with a column `Description` which contains something along the lines 
"1952 **Rolls Royce** Silver Wraith" or "1966 **Holden**".

I also have a separate dataset (Dataset "B") with a list of every `Car Brand` that I need (eg "**Holden**", "**Rolls Royce**", "Porsche").

How can I create a new column in dataset "A" that assigns the Partial strings of the `Description` with the correct `Car Brand`?

(This column would only hold the correct `Car Brand` with the appropriate matching cell).

Thank you.

`Description           New Column
 1971 Austin 1300       Austin`

Comment: Try with `fuzzy_left_join`

Comment: @akrun How does that command work, specifically with `match_fun = NULL, multi_by = NULL, multi_match_fun = NULL` ?

Comment: Next time, please provide sample data using `dput`, so other users can simply copy-paste, and do not have to re-type/guess your data.

Answer (score 1):

A solution from the tidyverse

```
A <- data.frame (Description = c("1970 Austin"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

B <- data.frame (Car_Brand = c("Austin"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
A %>% mutate( New_Column= str_match( Description, B$Car_Brand)[,1] )

#   Description New_Column
# 1 1970 Austin     Austin
```